# jest automocking decorators incorrectly

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I use this pattern in my tests to automock modules:

```js
jest.mock("module-that-exports-decorator")
```

Which gives me this error in my test

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: decorator is not a function
```

How to fix it without having to to manual mock for every exported decorator?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not a decorator you trying to use but it's a function that returns a decorator.

That means, if it's a function that returns a decorator usage will look like this:

```
// We invoke function with () so it will return a decorator.
@Foo()
class Bar {}
```

If that's the case, `jest.mock()` will just mock `Foo` and it will return `undefined` because of the jest mock.

So in reality, it will look something like below after Foo() call

```
@undefined
class Bar {}
```

Which is the reason of the error. It seems manual mock is the only way to fix that for now.